# Create unique array in Cython from memoryview

Tags: python, cython

I have a string list called `animals` which looks like:

```
['dog','dog','cat','cat','mouse','cat','bird','mouse']
```

I am trying to create a unique list in Cython that would look like:

```
['dog','cat','mouse','bird',]
```

The code that I have created to try and create this unique list is below:

This is the call to the function:

```
uniq_animal_list = unique_string_list(list animals)
```

This is the function:

```
def unique_string_list(list a):
    cdef int i
    cdef int n = len(a)
    cdef set s = set()
    for i in range(n):
        s.add(a[i])
    return s
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: Argument 'a' has incorrect type (expected list, got project.temp._memoryviewslice)
```

Comment: `list(set(['dog','dog','cat','cat','mouse','cat','bird','mouse']))`

Comment: Yes - just do it with Python types. I don't really understand your desire to convert string lists to memoryviews when they really aren't suitable.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Please show the *actual*, complete code you’re using to call your function. You said you used `unique_string_list(list animals)` but that’s invalid syntax.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: for now I have cast a "needs [mcve]" close vote. If this closes and the question is improved, please ping me to reassess.